# Angularjs ui-bootstrap btn-checkbox conditional styling

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-class

Would like to use btn-checkbox in place of all my checkboxes on a form. I am looking for the syntax to make a generic reference to the value of the bound property from within the attributes, in this case ng-class.

```
<button type="button" 
        ng-class="{true: 'btn btn-success', 
                   false:'btn btn-checkbox-off'}
                   [vm.csrMain.doubleAggregate]" 
        ng-model="vm.csrMain.doubleAggregate"
        btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false">
        DOUBLE AGGREGATE
</button>
```

( using ctrl as vm syntax )  The code above works, but I want to make a generic reference to the value of the ng-model in the brackets where I am hard coding the bound property [vm.csrMain.doubleAggregate] something like [ng-model.$value]

Tried to do a plunker here. Not sure why I can't get the btn-checkbox behavior I get successfully in the code above.  If someone could guide me on that as well I'd appreciate it as this my first shot at a plunk from scratch [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NjANjSsGUFIKSewOfsT8)

Comment: can you setup a plunker.. i will try to convert it to reusable directive

Comment: Thank you Harish.  While i've used plunker a lot to play with other people's plunks this is the first time I've tried to create one from scratch. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NjANjSsGUFIKSewOfsT8) Notes in description and md.  Works in my app but I may have set up plunk wrong as I don't get btn-checkbox behavior. Changed versions of bootstrap and ui-bootstrap to match my app.